# Including Bootstrap 4 In My Project

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 now ships with flex reboot and grid. I am not finding in the documentation anywhere if it is all included in bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css.

If I include bootstrap.min.css does that have everything? Or do I have to include 
bootstrap-flex.css bootstrap-grid.css and bootstrap-reboot.css separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexbox support is in bootstrap.css.  You can get a precompiled version with grid only or reboot only from http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/

For more info, see http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/